# Should I say 'a consequent result' or 'a consequential result'?

Tags: grammar

My doubt is between this:

```
The damage is a consequent result of the conflict
```

And this:

```
The damage is a consequential result of the conflict
```

I've found several references to this on the web, but haven't been able to decide which one is better in this context.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is: it depends what you mean!

Let's look at the definitions for (adjectives) **consequent** and **consequential** (both from Collins via TheFreeDictionary.com).

> consequent
>
> 1. following as an effect or result
> 2. following as a logical conclusion or by rational argument
> 3. (Physical Geography) (of a river) flowing in the direction of the original slope of the land or dip of the strata

And the other:

> consequential
>
> 1. important or significant
> 2. self-important; conceited
> 3. following as a consequence; resultant, esp indirectly: consequential loss.

So, in your example, if you think that the damage is particularly important, use consequential. If, on the other hand, the damage simply followed on as a result of the conflict, then use consequent.

Comment: My context is very distinctively under the first category. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, if you want to be clear and concise, you wouldn't use either.

Instead, you would say:

> The damage is a consequence of the conflict.

Cambridge Dictionary:

> consequence (noun) - a result of a particular action or situation, often one that is bad or not convenient. e.g. - "The accident was the inevitable consequence of carelessness."

In other words "consequent result" and "consequential result" are tautologies.